What kind of example application can I use for demonstrating asynchronous and synchronous behaviour in FastDDS
I am conducting a study on ROS2 Humble - FastDDS features. During my research, I encountered synchronous and asynchronous publishing modes. I identified several throughput controller parameters that can be utilized in asynchronous mode. Although I experimented with examples available in the FastDDS library, I'm seeking a deeper understanding of these modes and their operational differences. Could you provide example codes or offer suggestions to help me grasp these concepts?
